# Calling a REST API through JS and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written the below code to get the status of the REST service. But when I am clicking on the button, it is not doing any action. Please suggest what I am missing to get this code working.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
  function invokeService() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            url: "https://inf:7871/smcfs/heartbeat",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processData: true,
            success: function(result) {
              AjaxSucceeded(result);
            },
            eror: AjaxFailed
          });

          function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
            alert(result);
          }

          function AjaxFailed(result) {
            alert(result.status + '' + result.statusText);
          }
        }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <input type="button" önclick="javascript:invokeService();" value="Call WCF Service" />
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you setting a content type on a GET request? There is no content to describe the type of.

Comment: You misspelt `error`

Comment: I'm curious why you wouldn't use `async`. This may produce undesired slowdowns or page freezes.

Comment: You can split responsability and test one by one. First you should not make a ajax call and use only console.log when the button pressed. Then when this works you could make the ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute is called `onclick`, not `önclick`. This would have been picked up if you had used [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="invokeService()" value="Call WCF Service" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In whatever browser you are enable the developer mode and check the console You have some misspellings and errors and some of them will appear in the JavaScript console. Fix those errors and then you will have a better idea about what might be the problem.

In Google Chrome right click on the page and click inspect, then select the "Console Tab".
 In Firefox right click in the page and click "inspect element" and then select the console tab.

You can post a print screen of the output.